# Inequality involving absolute moment and variance

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, absolute-value, invariance

Suppose $X\in\Omega$ is a random variable and $f:\Omega\rightarrow [0,1]$.  Is the following true:

$$E[|f(X)-E[f(X)]|]^2\leq \operatorname{Var}[f(X)]?$$

This was stated without proof in a research paper (perhaps the proof is trivial, but I can't see it). I also wonder if the class of functions $f$ can be generalized (perhaps this is true for $f:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  By Jensen's inequality, $E(Y^2)\ge E(|Y|)^2$. Now use $Y=f-E(f)$, so that $E(Y^2)=Var(f)$.

Comment: Ahh, yes, that makes sense.  And, by the same argument, for any $0<a\leq b$, $E[|X|^a]^{1/a}\leq E[|X|^b]^{1/b}$, so $f$ doesn't matter in my case.